# Directorist - Dropdown doesn't open

Tags: plugins, javascript, html

I am using the Directorist plugin, and in the Filters, the select dropdown has a bug in it.
What I found out is that it is a SPAN with a SELECT inside.

[This is the page with the filter on the end of it](https://www.lidermotoslondrina.com.br/motos-semi-novas/)

I cannot figure out why it doesn't open if you click on top of it, but if you click in the bottom, it opens.
I guess it's a javascript error. But cannot find where since it gives me no errors.

Comment: All of the `<select>` elements on that page function fine for me in Brave - which browser are you using? That said, please note that support for third-party plugins is considered off-topic on this stack

Comment: I didn't know it was off-topic.
I'm using Chrome. But also on my phone it doesn't work properly.